# Is there a word that strictly means "mutual understanding?"

Tags: word-choice, idioms, synonyms

In an essay I've written, I come to realize something. Someone else understands that I've just realized this something.

> The engendered sense of achievement and understanding . . .

In this context, "understanding" can refer to both my understanding of the concept in question, and the mutual understanding or connection, so to speak, between myself and someone else.

How can I disambiguate this sentence? I'm trying to refer to the mutual understanding or connection between myself and someone else. I want to write "mutual understanding" in place of "understanding," but I used the phrase in this preceding sentence.

Comment: Very few words mean anything strictly.

Comment: perhaps "shared understanding".  Just BTW: I would be careful about using "engendered" it is typically superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

'tacit'--expressed or understood without being directly stated (Merriam-Webster.com). e.g.,'There was a tacit understanding that the marriage was doomed';'they had a tacit agreement that nothing would be done about it without direct orders.'

Answer (score 1):

I think [correspondence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Correspondence) can suggest the concept you referring to:

> - The act, fact, or state of agreeing or conforming.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 0):

This question happened to pop up among the allegedly "similar" ones, while I was writing one of my own...

I hope I'm not violating any rules by answering an eight year old query:

> [**rapport**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rapport)
>
> If two people or groups have a rapport, they have a good relationship
> in which they are able to understand each other's ideas or feelings
> very well.
>
> *The success depends on good rapport between interviewer and interviewee.*

A bit surprised, actually, that this has not already been suggested here.